# How to access a remote path from python code?

Tags: python, networking

I have a shared folder mounted on my machine using an smb path and I have to access it from inside a VM.

I tried using the smb path directly but it gives me the `NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE` error and it won't work. I decided to access it using remote path but I am not sure how to do that.

If I have `user@ip:/shared/path`, how do I access it from `os.walk`? I tried using `wnc` path module but it is giving me an invalid path when I enter it as:

```
simple_unc = UncDirectory(r'//IP_ADDR/PATH/ON/HOST/')
creds = UncCredentials('USER', 'PWD')
authz_unc = UncDirectory(r'\\USER@IP\\PATH\\ON\\HOST\\', creds)
```

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: In a raw string, don't double backslashes (unless you actually want two of them): `r'\\USER@IP\PATH\ON\HOST'`

Comment: Turns out I cannot use it at all(I am on Ubuntu). I tried mounting it using sshfs but still can't access it inside python.